# ANR while fastscrolling the listview with larger datasets

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I have android listview using SimpleCursorAdapter Adapter and fastscroll is enabled for the listview. If i have smaller datasets fast scroll work fine , but for large datasets( more than 4000 records) while fast scrolling the listview it will through ANR in
   a*ndroid.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)

at android.database.BulkCursorProxy.getWindow(BulkCursorNative.java:215)
  at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.onMove(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:104)
  at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:188)
  at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToPosition(CursorWrapper.java:187)
  at android.widget.AlphabetIndexer.getPositionForSection(AlphabetIndexer.java:202)*

and also logcat show
***10-19 11:40:20.664  3026  3215 D Cursor  : skip_rows row 41
10-19 11:40:20.773  3026  3215 E CursorWindow: need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 55, freeSpace() = 42, numRows = 2471
10-19 11:40:20.773  3026  3215 E CursorWindow: not growing since there are already 2471 row(s), max size 1048576
10-19 11:40:20.773  3026  3215 E Cursor  : Failed allocating 55 bytes for text/blob at 2511,14
10-19 11:40:20.796  3026  3215 D Cursor  : finish_program_and_get_row_count row 1614***

I think cursor is deallocating and allocating the memory for larger datasets. this lead to ANR

Let me know if you have any good solution to overcome this issues and thanks in advance

Regards,
Sathish

Answer (score 0):

Well, i had faced a similar issue.My suggestion to you would be create a custom ArrayAdapter instead of using a CursorAdapter.When the screen is to be shown, fetch the records in a backend thread from the database (Show a progressbar to the user till then), fill them in your custom Arrayadapter and display it to the user.Fetching all records will take time, but Android database is comparatively slower and you cannot do much for that.Once all the database objects in memory, your Fast scroll will be very fast as everything will be in memory.I have tested this with 30,000 records.

-----Optimizing your logic to save memory.------

Instead of fecthing a complete record set for all items, only fetch the Primary key for all items initially and pass it to your Custom ArrayAdapter. Override the getViews method and in that fetch the record for that particular id.You can null out the items which are not visible.In this way , only the visible 6 to 8 item records will be in memory.
Let me know if you have further queries in implementing this.